# Edit or remove picture button disabled in skype for business

Tags: office365, profile-picture, skype-for-business

Edit or remove button is disabled for me in Skype for business. I am also not able to update my profile picture in portal.office.com/Profile. It says access denied. Screenshots are attached[image]. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the Skype for Business main window, click the Options button, and then click Personal.

In Personal options, under Show pictures, clear the Show pictures of contacts check box.